# GLUT segmentation fault on glCreateShader

Tags: c++, c, glut, glew

I am writing C++ program with use of glew,glut and GLM.
When I am creating shader like this:

```
GLuint VertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
```

it says "Segmentation fault(core dumped)".
My hardware is Intel Atom CPU.
OS:OpenSuse 13.2 32-bit.
What I need to do to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not checking OpenGL extensions, version, or etc.

```
GLenum err = glewInit();
if (err != GLEW_OK)
  exit(1); // or handle the error in a nicer way
if (!GLEW_VERSION_2_1)  // check that the machine supports the 2.1 API.
  exit(1); // or handle the error in a nicer way
```

This code needs to happen after creating the OpenGL context, but before using any potentially-not-existing functions. More details on the [GLEW web page](http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html)